# Nginx, change param in condition

Tags: php, nginx

Have "heavy" page where need more time to load. 
Example page url: http://example.com/index.php?task=update&action=map (several arguments).

I expected the following nginx configuration (`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`):

```
server {
    #...
    location ~ \.php$ {
        set $isMap "";
        if ($arg_task = update) { set $isMap 1$isMap; }
        if ($arg_action = map)  { set $isMap 1$isMap; }
        if ($isMap = 11) {
            fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        }    
    }
}
```

But I got an error:
`"fastcgi_read_timeout" directive is not allowed here`

How can change timeout for specific page (url has arguments)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Never use fastcgi_* and proxy_* directives within if block.

Create separate named location for every fastcgi configuration variant and redirect to it

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  ...
  if(...)  {
    error_page 418 = @fastcgi_1;
    return 418;
  }
}

location @fastcgi_1 {
  fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

You should read http://agentzh.blogspot.ru/2011/03/how-nginx-location-if-works.html for details.

> Okay, you see how ngx_proxy module's config inheritance among nested
>   locations take the key role here, and make you believe it works the
>   way that you want. But other modules (like echo mentioned in one of my
>   earlier emails) may not inherit content handlers in nested locations
>   **(in fact, most content handler modules, including upstream ones,
>   don't)**.